# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to $OnSliderClickListener #377

Tags: android, slider

```
private void addAdvertisementBanner(){
for(String name : file_maps.keySet()){
    TextSliderView textSliderView = new TextSliderView(context);
    // initialize a SliderLayout
    BaseSliderView baseSliderView = textSliderView
            .description(name)
            .image(file_maps.get(name))
            .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit)
            .setOnSliderClickListener((BaseSliderView.OnSliderClickListener) context);

    //add your extra information
    textSliderView.bundle(new Bundle());
    textSliderView.getBundle()
            .putString("extra",name);

    mDemoSlider.addSlider(textSliderView);
}
mDemoSlider.setPresetTransformer(SliderLayout.Transformer.Accordion);
mDemoSlider.setPresetIndicator(SliderLayout.PresetIndicators.Center_Bottom);
mDemoSlider.setCustomAnimation(new DescriptionAnimation());
mDemoSlider.setDuration(4000);
mDemoSlider.addOnPageChangeListener((ViewPagerEx.OnPageChangeListener) context);
```

}

Please Help**How I can typecast that**
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{shyam.com.imageslider/shyam.com.imageslider.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderTypes.BaseSliderView$OnSliderClickListener #377
Unable to Start Activity

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
BaseSliderView baseSliderView = textSliderView
                .description(name)
                .image(file_maps.get(name))
                .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit)
                .setOnSliderClickListener(new BaseSliderView.OnSliderClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSliderClick(BaseSliderView slider) {

                    }
                });
```

Instead of this

```
 BaseSliderView baseSliderView = textSliderView
            .description(name)
            .image(file_maps.get(name))
            .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit)
            .setOnSliderClickListener((BaseSliderView.OnSliderClickListener) context);
```

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{shyam.com.imageslider/shyam.com.imageslider.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: shyam.com.imageslider.MainActivity cannot be cast to com.daimajia.slider.library.Tricks.ViewPagerEx$OnPageChangeListener

Comment: @ShyamSundar remove this line `mDemoSlider.addOnPageChangeListener((ViewPagerEx.OnPageChangeListener) context);`

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove import class of `com.daimajia.slider.library` from your activity and add import `com.glide.slider.library.SliderLayout;` to your activity and run again.